# Linear interpolation using scipy's interp1d

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, linear-regression, interpolation, approximation

I am trying to do a linear interpolation

Code:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x_ = [2.,   2.8, 16.7]
y_ = [0.87678869, 0.49044994, 1.4322675]
y_std = []
plt.plot(x_, y_, marker='o', color='k')
f = interp1d(x_, y_, kind='linear', bounds_error=False)

plt.plot(x_, f(x_), marker='o', color='tab:green')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I expected a linear line, but the result appears to be a piecewise fit.
Could someone please suggest what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolate just fills in the content between the points, and therefore it must hit every single point in your original dataset.

What you're looking for is to run a linear regression:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html